# How do I get the length of a number password for an edit text in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout

I have tried doing a text watcher

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
            val requiredLength = 4
            val editTextView: EditText = findViewById(R.id.pinInput)
```

unsure how to write this line of code to get the length

```
            val textLength = editTextView.text.length
    
    
            val submitButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)
    
            submitButton.setOnClickListener {
                
    
                
                if (textLength != requiredLength) {
                    error()
                } else {
                     success()
                }
    
            }
```

Should I be using a different view

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/pinInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/pin"
        android:maxLength="4"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Please help, also this is my first time posting content like this

Comment: Like Yunus says, you need to get the length in the click listener, just before you compare it to ``requiredLength``. Right now, when execution reaches the line `val textLength = editTextView.text.length` it reads the length of the text *at that moment*, assigns that value to a fixed ``val`` called ``textLength``, and that never changes. So in your click listener, you're checking if that length *at setup* was equal to `requiredLength` - you need to be reading the current length and comparing that

Comment: Thank you for the wisdom! I updated my code and it was a success! Haha!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should get the length when the button is pressed

```
    submitButton.setOnClickListener {
        val textLength = editTextView.text.length

        if (textLength != requiredLength) {
            error()
        } else {
            success()
        }

    }
```

Comment: Wow Haha! I appreciate you very much! This makes me happy; it worked!